# Does the attacker need to be on the same network to carry out a deauthentication attack?

Tags: wifi, deauth-attack

I'm sort of confused due to contradicting information about it but I just want to know if it's important for an attacker to be on the same Wifi network if he wants to deauthenticate another user?

Comment: Deauthenticate from what? If you're talking about, deauthenticating from the wifi, they just need to be in physical proximity of the router.

Comment: What are your sources that are providing the conflict?

Comment: @nobody the attacker doesn't even need to be near the router, only near to the client. In wifi, this is not always the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The attacker can deauth without being authenticated on the wifi network, but they must be within radio range of the access point.

Comment: Which station, the access point or the client?

Comment: Do they need to be near the AP or near the client? Isn't the client the more important party?

Comment: They need to be near the AP and know the MAC address of the client,  they can get the clients mac address by listening to messages from the AP.to the client or to messages from the client to the AP.  this is "radio near" so a high gain antenna pointed at the AP from a distance may suffice

Comment: It took me a while, but `aireplay-ng` sends deauth frames to both the AP and the client. So if using that tool, you are expected to be in range of both. I'm wondering if you need to be in range of the AP at all, though.

Comment: If you use jamming for indirect deauthentication you could be near either the router or the client.